# How to pass an array of hashes to controller WITHOUT form?

Tags: ruby, hash

What I have so far is an array of hashes I'm pulling from a Website via RestClient:

```
def self.all_galleries 
    JSON.parse(RestClient.get ENV["GALLERY_API"], {:accept => :json})
end
```

I wanted to then pass this array to my controller, and create and save a new object for every hash to my database ONLY IF it doesn't exist without using any sort of form. What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using Rails?  You might want to make that known...

Comment: Also, why are you using the controller?  Are you trying to pass this to your Rails app via an HTTP request (if, indeed, this is a Rails app)?

Comment: Yeah I am using rails. @totallymike, you're definitely right, Why am I using the controller? I decided it was a terrible idea to take that information and save it, when I already have access to the information using a HTTP request. So you pretty much answered my question by questioning it..